# Execute a query at once on several databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server database with several database (CustomerA, CustomerB, ....), all with the same structure.

Is it possible to execute at once a query on all databases (CustomerA, CustomerB, ....) ?

Below for one server :

```
Use CustomerA
GO
select * from Loggin.NLog where messages like '%error%'
```

The result I'd like is :

```
CustomerA
Row with error
Row with error
CustomerB
Row with error
```

Comment: You could create one view to combine all queries with UNION ALL, adding a new query each time you add a customer.

Comment: You can extend @oscar s answer by preparing a dynamic sql which unions all results and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using the (undocumented) sp `sp_MSforeachdb`:

```
USE master;
GO

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?
IF (''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''model'')) BEGIN
    PRINT ''Running query on ?'';
    SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName, * FROM Loggin.NLog WHERE messages LIKE ''%error%'';    
END';
```

Comment: I abuse of your knwoledge ....  and only when the database name begin by "MyDatabaseLoggin"

Comment: While it's a clean and easy solution, undocumented implies unsupported and that there is no guarantees about whether the procedure will exist in future versions of the product, so it must be used with caution.

Comment: @Kris-I If the database name has a specific prefix, then instead of using a `NOT IN` use a `LIKE` operator. Try yourself and comment back if you don't manage it.

Comment: @Oscar do agree on the fact it could "disappear", however, as it stands it's still in SQL Server 2017, and (iirc) it's been there since 2005/2000.

Comment: Ok perfect. One more thing, how can I display (if possible) the database name between the results in the results grid.

Comment: You won't be able to. A database name, on it's own, is only a single column, where as your dataset is using `SELECT *` (so returning several). You can't mix datasets with differing column numbers. If you want to include a header like that, do so in your Presentation layer. The query has been updated to return the name of the Database, so you could easily do this in SSRS using a Group, or even in Excel using a Pivot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the servers registered as linked servers in your ddbb, yes, you can.

```
select * from LinkedServer1.Loggin.NLog where messages like '%error%'
UNION ALL 
select * from LinkedServer2.Loggin.NLog where messages like '%error%'
```

Take a look [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/) about registering linked servers